# Nginx log to stderr

Tags: logging, nginx, stderr, systemd

I want to redirect nginx access logs to `stdout` to be able to analyze them through `journalctl` (systemd).

There is the same question with approved answer.
[Have nginx access_log and error_log log to STDOUT and STDERR of master process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22541333/have-nginx-access-log-and-error-log-log-to-stdout-and-stderr-of-master-process)
But it does not work for me. With `/dev/stderr` I get `open() "/dev/stderr" failed (6: No such device or address)`. With `/dev/stdout` I get no access logs in `journalctl -u nginx`.

nginx.conf

```
daemon off;

http {
    access_log /dev/stdout;
    error_log /dev/stdout;
    ...
}
...
```

sitename.conf

```
server {
    server_name sitename.com;
    root /home/username/sitename.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        access_log on;
    }
}
```

nginx.service

```
[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/nginx.pid
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=nginx
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g 'master_process on;'
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g 'master_process on;'
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/nginx -g 'master_process on;' -s reload
ExecStop=-/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid
TimeoutStopSec=5
```

I've tried my best to workaround that by changing every possible parameter in the code above and with different nginx versions (1.2, 1.6) but without any success.

I'm really, really interested how to make this work so I raise this question again on a different thread as I consider previous answer is wrong, speculative or environment specific.

```
$ journalctl -u nginx
```

contains only lines like

```
 Feb 08 13:05:23 Username systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

and no sign of access logs :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#error_log), the `error_log` directive supports `stderr` as its argument. The following configuration should therefore log error messages to stderr:

```
http {
    error_log stderr;
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately, `access_log` doesn't support `stdout` as its argument. However, it should be possible to set it to `syslog` ([documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#access_log)) and get systemd to include syslog calls into its journal.

Answer (score 20):

```
server {
    error_log syslog:server=unix:/dev/log;
    access_log syslog:server=unix:/dev/log;
    ...
}
```

Default journald configuration (I'm running Ubuntu 15.04) reads from syslog, so this config is all it takes to have logs be viewable with `journalctl -u nginx`

Comment: stderr didn't work for me, but this config did. Thanks!