# How to work with variables in DOCKERFILE

Tags: docker

I am creating NGINX container. I want to write all logs into a mounted volume rather than the default volume. This I can achieve by updating nginx.conf file by pointing access_log and error_log to a folder in mounted volume. The twist is that I want each container to write to container specific folder within the mounted volume.

For eg:
Container image name: `mycontainerapp`
Mounted volume: `/logdirectory`
Then I want:
`/var/log` to point to `/logdirectory/mycontainerapp/{containerID}/log`

This way, I can have multiple containers log to the common mounted volume.

AFAIK, I can get container ID from /proc/1/cpuset
I am not sure of any other way to get the container ID

Question is, how can I read that containerID and use it to create the mounted volume (with folder name) using DOCKERFILE?

Also, if there is a better approach to what I am trying to achieve, please do let me know as I am a newbie to docker.

Comment: Do you want to read the container Id from the host or from a container? See ` docker ps` and ` docker inspect` at least

Answer (score 0):

Docker has a [logging mechanism](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/view_container_logs/) included which removes standard log files from the equation. All data sent to `stdout` and `stderr` will be captured by Dockers logging interface.

There are a number of [logging drivers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/) that can then ship logs from your Docker host to a central logging service (Graylog, Syslog, AWS CloudWatch, ETW, Fluentd, Google Cloud, Splunk). The `json` driver is the default which is locally stored on the Docker host. `journald` will also be stored and accessible locally.

In nginx config, or any container for that matter, [send the access log `stdout` or `/dev/fd/1` and send the error log to `stderr` or `/dev/fd/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23328458/1318694)

```
daemon off;
error_log /dev/fd/2 info;

http {
  access_log /dev/fd/1;
  ...
}
```

Once you start applying this concept to all containers, any log management requirements are removed from the container/application level and pushed up to the host. Container [meta data can be attached to logs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/#use-environment-variables-or-labels-with-logging-drivers). It becomes easier to move or change the logging mechanism. Moving to clustered setups like Swarm becomes less of a hassle. This all ties into the 1 process per container idea of the world that Docker pushes.